# find historical stock prices of stocks using datareader but could not find for stovks on bse

Tags: python

import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ibm = wb.DataReader('IBM', data_source='yahoo', start='2019-1-1')
ibm

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a little more details. Are you getting any errors? If yes, please add the full error message. If your code runs but the output is wrong, please add what is your current output and expected output.

Also, do not write your problem in the title, keep the title short and meaningful. Write down your problem in the description.